# Drop down list with an empty option using flask wtforms

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I want the following drop down lists to have an empty option:

```
form.from_location.choices = [("","-")] + [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
form.to_location.choices = [("", "-")] + [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
```

(Someone had asked this question here before and this code snippet was the solution to that, but it doesn't work for me, I keep getting this error- `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`)

I also tried this and got the same error:

```
form.from_location.choices.insert(0, (0, None))
form.to_location.choices.insert(0, (0, None))
```

This is the code for the table:

```
class Movement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False)
    product = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    from_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    from_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    to_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    to_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

And this is the code for the form:

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
    product = SelectField("Product", choices = [])
    from_location = SelectField("From Location", choices = [])
    to_location = SelectField("To Location", choices = [])
    quantity = StringField("Quantity", validators=[DataRequired()])
    add_movement = SubmitField("Add Movement")
```

Comment: Try changing `form.from_location.choices.insert(0, (0, None))` to `form.from_location.choices.insert(0, (0, "")).` Also you may need to change `from_location = SelectField("From Location", choices = [])` to `from_location = SelectField("From Location", choices = [], coerce=int)`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error(```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'```).

Comment: And what objects id is it trying to get? so, which object is None?