# How do you use the function parameter blank for SelectField in WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I've been trying to create a drop down list with a blank option using `SelectField` on `wtforms` and I've tried all the methods I've seen suggested here before(that question was asked quite a lot here), but none of them worked for me. The methods that failed included:

```
form.from_location.choices = [("","-")] + [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
```

and

```
form.from_location.choices.insert(0, (0, None))
```

(For more details: [Drop down list with an empty option using flask wtforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042783/drop-down-list-with-an-empty-option-using-flask-wtforms))

I came across an unrelated question here where they made use of the function parameter `blank` to do so, but I didn't quite understand how they used it and I couldn't find anything about it in the docs either. Could someone please explain how to use it?

Comment: Hey! Could you provide a [minimum, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? Would love to take a look and copy your code into my IDE :-)

Comment: Hi, could you see if this helps- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042783/drop-down-list-with-an-empty-option-using-flask-wtforms)? It contains the relevant code snippets, but if not, I'll be happy to provide the minimum reproducable example.